# How to Load a WPF window in the MainWindow as a TabControl item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame, tabitem

The structure of my MainWindow.xaml is as bellow

```
<Window>
   <Grid>
    <TabControl Name="MainTabCntrl">
       <TabItem1>
       <TabItem2>
       <TabItem3>
       .
       .
       .
       <TabItemN>
    </TabControl>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem is that my MainWindow.xaml is currently ~4000 lines of code,which is not efficient(do you agree?) 
the solution I'm trying to implement is to create N windows (representing my TabItems) separately and each time user click on Tab items I load the related windows in that TabItem as shown bellow

```
 private void inventory_start()//this function is called in my MainWinodw.xaml.cs
        {
            inv = new Inventory(db, logViewer);//this is a window
            TabItem tbItem = new TabItem();
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Content = inv;
            tbItem.Name = "invTab";
            tbItem.Content = frame;
            tbItem.IsSelected = true;
            MainTabCntrl.Items.Add(tbItem);
            inv.swithInventoryTabs("inv_info");
        }
```

I have an error now , "'Management_V0.Inventory' root element is not valid for navigation."

Comment: How about having `Inventory` and the other tab contents being a `UserControl` or some other kind of window *Content* instead of being a `Window`? I think there are easier answers for the question how to create N separate TabItem contents than answering how to load nested windows (which you probably don't need anyway).

Comment: @ grek40 Thanks for your answer , whats your opinion about creating  N separate TabItem contents?

Comment: I can close-vote this question for *"primarily opinion-based"* if that's what you are asking for. Please follow the question guidelines and state your specific problems instead of asking for opinions.

Comment: Actually I asked my question in the first line " The problem is that my MainWindow.xaml is currently ~4000 lines of code,which is not efficient(do you agree?)" the problem which raise this question is "efficiency".

Comment: And of course  the second question was the error which was replied by you and mm8 :)

Comment: But *efficient* is not a rational thing. Depending on the business case, getting a result within an hour might be *efficient* or it might be required to get results within a few milliseconds. Does your current implementation take longer than an hour? If not, why do you want to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A window *cannot* be a child of another element. Period.

But you could just move the contents of the `Inventory` window to a `UserControl` (by for example simply copy and paste the XAML and the code from one file to another) and use this one as the `Content` of the `Inventory` window and the `Frame`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Inventory"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Inventory" Height="300" Width="300">
    <local:UserControl1 />
</Window>
```

---

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
frame.Content = new UserControl1();
```

Comment: Thanks dear @mm8  I've got it , no window.
and whats your opinion about the whole thing? is this necessary to lighten the mainwindows.xaml or its not?

Comment: Well, if the contents of the MainWindow is that large I guess it makes sense to separate the code into several different UserControls. Note that you can set the Content of the TabItem to a UserControl directly, you don't need the Frame.

Answer (score 1):

best way to use tabControl is with User control: Example below:
XAML

```
 <TabControl >
                <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="UserControl"></TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="noControl"></TabItem>
            </TabControl>
```

and in code behind class:

```
  tab1.Content = new UserControl1();
```

and than Add new user control of name UserControl1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="User Control"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```